# What should I do to apply a different color to each bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my code currently:

```py
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns

pibpercápita=pd.read_excel("E:\\Bases de Datos\\PIBpercápita2019.xlsx")

df=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel("E:\\Bases de Datos\\PIBpercápita2019.xlsx"))

df.groupby('Country Name').sum().plot(kind='barh',color=['g'],legend='Reverse')
```

Comment: in your `df.groupby(...` you have a list `color = ['g']`. There you can just add all the colors for your bars.

Comment: Yes, I did that, I puted different color, but It only taked the first

Comment: Okay, could you show the exact example which you did?

Answer (score 0):

Use the color parameter to plt.bar() to change the bar colors in Matplotlib. color can be a scalar value to change the color universally or an array to change the color of each bar individually.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['Amy', 'Rob', 'Dimitri', 'Sarah', 'Brian']
values = [60, 56, 63, 75, 48]

# Change the bar colors here
plt.bar(labels, values, color=['red', 'blue', 'purple', 'green', 'lavender'])

plt.ylabel('Typing Speed (wpm)')
plt.show()
```

Source: [Change the bar colors in a Matplotlib bar plot](https://showmecode.info/matplotlib/bar/change-bar-color/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want more color difference, go with seaborn color palette and visit the below link.
https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html